# When using GitHub Actions, how can I run my Terraform on my AWS environment?

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I am migrating my deployment from Jenkins to GitHub Actions.

I understand how to pull from my repository, build, test my application.
But one of the steps I currently perform inside of Jenkins is to update my infrastructure using Terraform. This means the code has to run on an instance running in my AWS environment.

How is this possible when using GitHub Actions?

Comment: If you need to run something in your own environment it would have to be a [self-hosted runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners), or you provide something that can proxy between a GitHub-hosted runner and your environment.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Self-host runner environment to  default runners of GitHub Actions.The simple reason is security issues that arise with default runners,you must provide them AWS Secret Access Keys and IDs.This is the excellent module [terraform-aws-github-runner](https://github.com/philips-labs/terraform-aws-github-runner) that I used for my project.

Comment: so a self hosted runner runs the github actions VM in your own environment, so it can trigger actions without giving your aws credentials to github?

Comment: It still requires the credentials or instance profile (any means in AWS context). Authorization and Authentication are not touched however on the network layer it is able to communicate with your current infrastructure if allowed (security groups/ACL) . 

 `This means the code has to run on an instance running in my AWS environment.`  : Not really it only means that from whichever machine you are executing your terraform code it should be able to authenticate itself to your aws infra and able to communicate on the network layer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup AWS Access using [AWS Credentials Configure action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/configure-aws-credentials-action-for-github-actions). You can use these credentials to run a SSM document for your instances through the GitHub Actions workflow either via the AWS CLI or a script in your repository. SSM documents run directly on the instances.